# Trouble with the process substitution in the file command

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

Easier to show as trying to describe with words.

```bash
find . -name jo\* -print > list
cat list
#./jo1
#./jo2
#./jo3

# the "file" by reading the list of files from the file "list"
file -f list
#./jo1: ASCII text
#./jo2: ASCII text
#./jo3: ASCII text

#now with process substitution
file -f <(find . -name jo\* -print)
```

outputs nothing.. ;(

```
#repeat with -x
set -x
file -f <(find . -name jo\* -print)
set +x

#shows
+ file -f /dev/fd/63
++ find . -name 'jo*' -print
+ set +x
```

so, it **should** work. But doesnt. why?

**EDIT**

Please note - the process substitution should work everywhere you should enter filename, let say:

```
diff <(some command) <(another command)
```

the bash the above uses as

```
diff /dev/fd/... /dev/fd/...
```

also for example in `grep` - you can use:

```
grep -f <(command_for_produce_the_patterns) files..
```

again, the `bash` internally uses this as

```
grep -f /dev/fd/63 files....
```

So, the same **should** work in the `file`

```
file -f <(command)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing things right. It's a bug in your implementation of `file`, which I can reproduce on mine (file 5.22 on Debian jessie). It expects the argument to `-f` to be a seekable file, and doesn't detect the error when the file isn't seekable. That's why it works with a regular file, but not with a pipe (which is what process substitution uses to pass the data between the two processes).

You can observe what's going on with `strace`:

```
$ strace file -f <(echo foo)
…
open("/proc/self/fd/13", O_RDONLY)      = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFIFO|0600, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
…
read(3, "foo\n", 4096)                 = 5
…
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_SET)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

The file program opens the list of file names on file descriptor 3 and reads it. The it tries to seek back to the beginning of the file. This fails, but the program reads from the file again, which yields no data since the file position is already at the end. Thus file ends up with an empty list of file names.

In the source code, the `-f` option triggers the `unwrap` function:

```
private int
unwrap(struct magic_set *ms, const char *fn)
{
    // …
    if (strcmp("-", fn) == 0) {
            f = stdin;
            wid = 1;
    } else {
        if ((f = fopen(fn, "r")) == NULL) {
                (void)fprintf(stderr, "%s: Cannot open `%s' (%s).\n",
                    progname, fn, strerror(errno));
                return 1;
        }
        while ((len = getline(&line, &llen, f)) > 0) {
            // … code to determine column widths
        }
        rewind(f);
    }
    // Code to read the file names from f follows
}
```

If the file name isn't `-` (instructing to read from standard input) then the code reads the file twice, once to determine the maximum width of the file names and once to process the files. The call to `rewind` is missing error handling. With `-` as a file name, the code doesn't try to align the columns.

Answer (score -2):

Instead of using the <(cmd) syntax, use $(cmd). This should overcome the bug

Comment: Do you know the difference between the `<(cmd)` and `$(cmd)`? If yes, you know that this isn't a solution. Also, just imagine, what will happen if the filenames will contain some spaces...

Comment: You are correct in that space in the file names would cause issues with a solution such as file $(find . -name jo\* -printf %f' ') (although there are no spaces in the example and so it is assumed that there are no spaces to deal with)  An alternate solution, taking spaces into account would be find . -name jo\* -exec file '{}' \;

Comment: I know how to solve the problem (one way is your suggestion, the other is `find ... | file -f -` and here are at least two others. ;) But the merit of the question is _why the process substitution doesn't works?_ (And I got the accepted answer :) ) Anyway, thank you for your interest.